# Работа с памятью программы (игры)

Tags: c#

Собственно, есть игра. Пытаюсь считать данные об жизнях пользователя. Процесс определил в Cheat Engine 283B2E48. Есть какие-нибудь примеры чтения данных на c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтение памяти чужого процесса — системно-зависимая штука, поэтому в самом языке этого нет.

Вам нужно воспользоваться WinAPI, в котором для этого есть специальная функция [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (и парная к ней [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Если вы пишете на C#, вам понадобятся P/Invoke-сигнатуры. Их можно подсмотреть [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670373/Csharp-Read-Write-another-Process-Memory) вместе с примером использования.