# Остановка времени в программе извне (получаемого из timeGetTime)

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, таймер

Есть ли способ подцепить функцию получения времени через `timeGetTime` в сторонней программе?

В данной ситуации я хотел бы пойти по одному из путей:

1) Заморозить время, получаемое через эту функцию.
2) Заменять возвращаемые значение на свои собственные (подмена) для дальнейшей работы в программе.

Не знаю с чего начать, да и возможно ли это вообще. Тем не менее спрашиваю здесь, чтобы навели хотя бы на мысль. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Под Linux это же самое делается с помощью `faketime`. Может быть можно завести программу под виртуалкой, которая в свою очередь работает под линуксом и с faketime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если программа не ваша, и вам нужно управлять значениями в ней, я вижу несколько вариантов решения, и они не такие уж и простые.

Вам нужно найти это значение с помощью `ArtMoney` или `CheatEngine`, после этого создать сигнатуру поиска этого адреса и после этого в вашей программе перебирать с помощью этой маски значения в ОЗУ и изменять их так, как вам это нужно. Также таким способом можно будет и замораживать таймер в другой программе.

Возможно, будут полезна эта ссылка:

[Работа с памятью программы (игры)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/372580/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B)

Либо писать свою библиотеку (точно не на `C#`), кормить ее этой программе.

Comment: Спасибо, это как раз то, что мне нужно =В